# Subscribe to action in one React component published from another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Imagine the following situation: we've developed two smart components and released two npm packages. After that we imported components to third React application which developed by another team.

***package.json***

```
"dependencies": {
  "component-ui1": "0.1.1",
  "component-ui2": "0.1.0"
}
```

***App.jsx***

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import ComponentUI1 from 'component-ui1';
import ComponentUI2 from 'component-ui2';

export const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
       // Some asynchronous actions
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <ComponentUI1 someProp={true} />
            <ComponentUI2 someProp={false} />
        </>
    );
};
```

How can I generate an event in `ComponentUI1` through DOM so that it triggers an action in `ComponentUI2`, for example, updating some list? Preferably without modifying logic of source components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ComponentUI1 from 'component-ui1';
import ComponentUI2 from 'component-ui2';

export const App = () => {

    const [state, setState] = useState({ComponentUI1List: [], ComponentUI2List: []});

    useEffect(() => {
       // Some asynchronous actions
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <ComponentUI1 state={state} changeState={(data) => setState(data)} />
            <ComponentUI2 state={state} changeState={(data) => setState(data)} />
        </>
    );
};
```

now in your ComponentUI1 or 2 you can change `ComponentUI1List` or `ComponentUI2List` like so:

```
// ComponentUI1.jsx
import React from 'react';

export const App = (props) => 

     (
        <>
            <div className="container">
              <button onClick=(props.changeState({...props.state, ComponentUI2List: [{id: 1, title: "New Generated Data"}]}))
            </div>
        </>
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! It will work, but is there any way to do this without modifying the source components?

Comment: of course , you should make `props.changeState({...props.state, ComponentUI2List: [{id: 1, title: "New Generated Data"}]})` dynamically, how? you need one more props like `someProps` and then implement like this `props.changeState({...props.state, ComponentUI2List: props.someProps})`, don't forget to pass `someProps`

Comment: thank you! Exploring this question I also find interesting library on github https://github.com/smff/dom-pubsub
It allows you to subscribe on actions by native way

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it is

1. make component ComponentUI2 a fully controlled or partially
   controlled component. Let the patent pass the list in. Expose a prop
   someList
2. Let component ComponentUI1 fire a event 'someEvent' when the said event is fired inside ComponentUI1
3. Make the parent container make the update

   ```
   import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
       import ComponentUI1 from 'component-ui1';
       import ComponentUI2 from 'component-ui2';

   export const App = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
      // Some asynchronous actions
   }, []);

   const [listAbc, setListAbc] = useState(0);

   const eventAbc = () = {
     //... update listAbc
     // setListAbc()
   }

   return (
       <>
           <ComponentUI1 someProp={true} someEvent={eventAbc} />
           <ComponentUI2 someProp={false} someList={listAbc} />
       </>
   );
   ```

   };